# Error dispatch-nio is not found

Tags: scala, sbt, scala-2.10, scala-dispatch

I m trying out the example given at http://dispatch-classic.databinder.net/Choose+an+Executor.html for dispatch-nio:
Example given:

```
import dispatch._
val h = new nio.Http
val f = h(url("http://www.scala-lang.org/") as_str)
```

My code:

```
  import dispatch._
  val h = new nio.Http
  var host = "http://www.scala-lang.org";
    val f: Future[String] = h(url("http://www.scala-lang.org/") as_str)
    f.apply();
```

But it doesn't recognize nio and as_str keywords. Could anyone please suggest what would be the problem?

Comment: What is in your build.sbt?

Comment: name := "blank"

version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

scalaVersion := "2.10.2"
 
resolvers += "Typesafe Repository" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq (
 "org.scalatest" % "scalatest_2.10" % "1.9.1" % "test"
)


libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "net.databinder" %% "dispatch" % "0.8.10"
)


libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "net.databinder.dispatch" %% "dispatch-core" % "0.11.2"
)

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "net.databinder" %% "dispatch-http" % "0.8.10"
)

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "net.databinder" %% "dispatch-nio" % "0.8.10"
)

Comment: Try changing the dispatch-nio dependency to the one from my answer and import dispatch.classic._ in the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure of your version but I've got it to work with `0.8.1`, the namespace looks like it's changed from the documentation.

In `build.sbt`:

`libraryDependencies += "net.databinder" %% "dispatch-nio_2.10.2" % "0.8.1"`

In code:

```
import dispatch.classic._

val h = new nio.Http
var host = "http://www.scala-lang.org";
val f = h(url("http://www.scala-lang.org/") as_str)
f.apply()
```

You may need to substitute the `2.10.2` in the library dependency with your scala version number.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Spork. It is working. Where can I find the updated documentation of dispatcher?

Comment: No problem, as far as I'm aware the only documentation is on the website. I managed to find the change using import completion in my IntelliJ IDE.

You can always check the project on GitHub if the documentation doesn't seem to be working. https://github.com/dispatch/dispatch

Comment: I would like to know that if I use dispatch.Http then I cannot use nio.Http ??

Thank you.